# Fallout 3 - Broken Steel - Nothing Happening

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-3

So I installed broken steel/point lookout on my xbox.  Then I put in the Fallout 3 disk and selected continue from last saved game.

I find myself in the rotunda about to activate the purifier.  I find whether I activate the purifier or not, I die a few seconds later and get shown a black and white movie highlighting the character's life, and then credits for the game.

How do I start the expansions?  Why is the game ending here even after I installed the expansion packs?  The game does give me notices while in the rotunda like "there's a boat going to point lookout" or something, and "broken steel activated".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either choice you make in the rotunda will "kill" you.  It will show you the black and white film and apparently "end" the game even with the expansion.  However, after the "end" finishes, it should allow you to continue (unlike without the expansion, where I believe it just takes you back to the main menu).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that.  I didn't even think to wait that long.  They should include instructions or something.